# Civi CRM Monthly lucky draw

Tags: wordpress

We are trying to set up a lucky draw on our site with Civi CRM.

Essentially, this is what needs to happen:

The user should be able to select how many tickets they would like to take (this is a random number generated by the system)

The user can then pay for the tickets.

The admin people are notified about the purchase.

An email is sent to the user telling them they have been entered into the draw.

The draw then takes place and the user is notified by email they are the lucky winners.

The numbers are then added back to the system when the draw is over.

These draws need to be relevant to the current month.

How could we achieve this? Or if someone could point me in the right direction please?

Comment: what CMS? I see you tagged as webform-civicrm which implies Drupal but you may not be aware of that subtlety

Comment: Sorry, I have amended the tags, it is on WordPress.

Comment: Could you clarify if the users are also contacts in CiviCRM? Is this lottery for members only?

Answer (score 1):

As you are on WordPress, I would suggest you start by looking for WordPress plugins that might do this for you. A [quick search for 'lottery'](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/lottery/) returned quite a few potential plugins that might help.

I'm not clear whether this needs to relate to your contacts in CiviCRM at all (i.e. if it is for members only). It may be that your solution has nothing to do with CiviCRM and is purely on the WordPress side. If so, you may find more help from the [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).